# Value VBA read from file different as declared value

Tags: excel, vba, regional-settings

My file write VBA code for read sheet name Thailand language.

A module VBA, I declare a variable SHEET_NAME_1 = " การคำนวณราคา", it corresponding sheet name " การคำนวณราคา".
But when run VBA code, SHEET_NAME_1 gets value is " ｡ﾒﾃ､ﾓｹﾇｳﾃﾒ､ﾒ".
I tried change format font to Thai [image]

But it still receive value look like Japanese value.

I tried change region to Thailand too
[image]

Because value receive from code different as sheet name so error happened

[image]

How can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I put it in the answer but I am not sure if this is going to help you.
In excel, click on files, below you will find options. Click Language. Can it be your settings here are not for Tailand?

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. It not working, it only change font display screen language, when I run code, it still same error.

Comment: Please have a look at the link, it seems to have to do with a language package not being installed.. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-is-opening-sheet-with-arabic-name-and/48dba7a0-7e9b-42af-aea3-490d0ce884cd